# Simulating pad button press with GPIO rPI3

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

So, i have very limited knowledge when it comes to electrical components. I have a decent amount of programming experience however.

I am trying to simulate a button press (big middle button in linked picture below). However, nothing seems to happen when i change the GPIO to high or low. I have checked with a multimeter and it is changing voltage but i guess thats not enough?

If i ground the other (top part) of the button, it does trigger the button but this happens even if the rpi is off (and ofc regardless of gpio setting). The lower part of the button is attached to a leg on some chip and the top seems to be connected to the battery (3v watch battery)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

What ive tried:

1. Soldering jumper between leg on chip and the other side of the button works like normal.
2. Soldering either point to gpio (only 1) has no effect. (Regardless of gpio settings)
3. Soldering chip leg to gpio and other to ground makes the button always trigger, even when rpi is off and regardless of gpio settings.

https://i.postimg.cc/CLdnP4GX/20190807-231615.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Need a relay:
I just did this for automatically opening my window blinds.  Clean off the +/- pads, then:
1) solder wires, 1 to each ground and voltage.
2) take voltage side wire and input to RELAY Common input port(screw).
3) take ground side wire and input to RELAY NO output port(screw).
4) wire up relay, Vcc=5V, Ground (pins).
5) Choose a GPIO output, wire to relay S1 input (through a 1K resistor). this is your trigger/switch.

When you toggle the GPIO, it will active/close the relay connecting each end of the pad switch. I had to create a 'pulse' for on/off, (turn it on, pause a few seconds, then turn if off) to simulate an actual button press.